# General Link Type Field - how to add another insert Option

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I am using the General Link Field to insert a URL in Sitecore.

I want to create a custom insert option (Don't want to override the GeneralLink Field), but I can't find any documentation related to it. The new insert option is to enter tel schema links (eg: ***tel:99999999***)

Does anyone have done this or has any idea?

Comment: FYI I have created this at Sitecore support as a feature wish. If you do the same it might get higher priority. Not that it helps you much right now.

Comment: Thanks, @JensMikkelsen . What's the link to it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this at the moment. But if you would like to insert simple text (like an email address or a phone number) wihout additional infos (i.e. linking to a specific item with a specific alternative text etc.) I would recommend to using a Single-Line Text field with a specific validator. So the author is free to fill in a phone number/email and gets reminded if the format is not correct.

Comment: I have to use General Link Field here, as the field is not just to enter telephone numbers, but also could be used to enter URLs - sort of a generic field.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you would like to create a new menu item for general link if so switch to core database and add your custom menu item here /sitecore/system/Field types/Link Types/General Link/Menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this custom Link schema using "Insert Javascript" Option available on the General Link field.

OR you can create your own custom made general Link field to the Core DB and have it listed into the template .

You can find it out at this location : /sitecore/system/Field types/Link Types/General Link

Hope This Helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use below given blog for reference

http://sitecorecode.com/index.php/2012/06/27/add-new-tab-in-general-link-field-type-of-sitecore/

Comment: This link is broken

Comment: Sorry @demisx sometime company you worked form change the blogs sites and now new links is http://sitecorecode.com/index.php/2012/06/27/add-new-tab-in-general-link-field-type-of-sitecore/